# Is the use of const necessary here?

Tags: c++

I am starting to come to grips with const in terms of a reference parameter. The way I see it is that a constant reference parameter basically sets the parameter in question to the original memory space that calls the function into question. And since it is const, the value in itself cannot change.

I have found a solution with regards to a code that delivers matrix multiplication `A=BC`:

```
vector<vector<double> > mult(const vector<vector<double> >& B, const vector<vector<double> >& C)
{ ...;
return A;
}

int main()
{
vector<vector<double> > B, C;
cout << mult(B,C) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I agree with the structure of the code but I am confused about the neccessity of "const" and  "&". Surely the code would be exactly the same if I excluded both from the above? For "&" one could perhaps that we use less memory space by not creating an extra space for the parameters of "mult". But the use of const seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: I would place const in front of arguments just like you did to make sure mult function is not changing B and C accidentally. It would be hard to debug if mult function was silently changing the B and C. Its just a safety feature added to function `mult`.

Comment: Without the reference, copy or move construction will commence (in this case copy). Without the `const`, the  arguments are mutable. If neither of those actions are desirable, you want them both. A function that is *supposed* to be multiplying two matrices shouldn't have to modify them. Enforcing that at compile-time is intentional. And no, the code would not be "exactly the same". It may result in the same end-multiplication, but the means to get it would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not *really* necessary. As long as you pass in non-`const` parameters to your function, the program will not behave differently.

I can state a few examples in your case:
If one of the parameters you have to pass is `const`, it will not work.
Furthermore, you won't be able to do something like `mult({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, b);` because that temporary object can only implicitly convert into a `const` reference.
If you put the definition and declaration in separate translation units (i.e. `.cpp` files) then the compiler might miss some optimization potential, because it wouldn't be able to assume that `mult()` doesn't modify its parameters.
Another argument is simply that `const` shows your intents more clearly.
See a few more reasons on [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

The reference `&` prevents an unnecessary copy. Your parameter type is a `std::vector`, which means that copying will involve memory allocations, and for performance reasons you do not want that.

On a side note, if your code is meant to manipulate matrices, then a `std::vector` of `std::vector` is very inappropriate for performance reasons, as it makes it extremely cache inefficient and causes unnecessary dynamic allocations. You would rather use a 1D `std::array` and wrap it to handle 2D indices nicely. `std::array` has sizes known as compile time, which means that every function you pass a specific `std::array` to knows its size on compile-time which is good for performance, especially as `std::array` makes it possible to avoid dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

The '&' prevents the copy constructor from being called, i.e., prevents a duplicate copy being made.  It is more efficient this way because you avoid the constructor on the invocation and the destructor on the exit.

The 'const' keyword communicates to the caller that the object to which the reference refers will not be changed in the function.  It also allows the function to be called with constant vectors as input.  In other words, if B and C are constant, you couldn't call mult() without the const keyword in the signature.

It's been a while in C++ for me, but I think that's the gist.  I'm certainly open to corrections on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few times when a `const` reference is, strictly-speaking, *necessary*.  The most common is when you need to pass a `const` object by reference.  The type system will prevent this unless the function promises not to modify the object.  It can also make a difference when a function is overloaded to do something different when the object is `const`, and you specifically want the `const` version. (The latter is probably bad design!)

It would alternatively be possible to remove the `const` qualifier from the function argument, and to give any overloaded functions different names.  In fact, references in C++ are syntactic sugar for C-style pointers, and it would be possible to replace `void foo (T& x)` with `void foo(T* x)` and every occurrence of `x` inside `foo` with `(*x)`. Adding `const T&` or `T* const` simply means that the program will not be able to modify the object through that reference or pointer.

C had no `const` keyword until 1989, and you could do all the same things without it, but it’s present in order to help developers avoid bugs related to modifying the wrong variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum(const int a,int b)
{
  b=10;
  // a=5; error
  return (a+b);
}
```

in above example `a` is const and not `b`.
So `a` as read-only variable. If you try to change the value of `a` you get error. That means you have to use value of `a` which pass when function is call.